# How to disable all Ip address except my ip address in linux iptables

Tags: linux, iptables

I need to disable all ip address including all ports except few ip address. I want to access the server only from few ip address, i do not want to access the server from other ip address.

Comment: What have you tried? [Server Fault is a site for Professional System and Network Administrators](http://serverfault.com/faq) -- We expect you to have done some research, and even attempted to find a solution on your own.  "Please do this for me" / "Be my Google" questions are not really appropriate here.  See [this Meta topic](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608) for more information on how to improve your question into one that may attract some more helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

This is explained all over the Internet and doesn't really require a question here, as it really is very easy to find via a search engine;

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/01/iptables-fundamentals/

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-examples.html

http://null.53bits.co.uk/index.php?page=iptables-notes